# code for submit button works in ff but not in ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

the following code works in FF, but it does not work in IE8.

```
<a class="sub">
<input type="submit" a="" none;<="" display:="">
</a>
```

The button is displayed, but the button is not clickable in IE8. What is going on?

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to be, be it's not valid markup at all.

Comment: What's going on inside that input tag?

Comment: Some rendering engines are able to fix bad markup, but doubt if IE's is one of them.

Comment: Is that html? I've never seen such weird attribute markups.

Comment: @HansStam if you've resolved it remember to share your answer or mark one of the answers below if they helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a correctly formed input submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I noticed the words `display` and `none` usually you'd find it in the following form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;"> // this however will hide the button
```

The attribute of `type=` with the value of `"submit"` makes our input tag into a submit button.

The attribute of `value=` with the value of `"Submit"` displays "Submit" text on our input button.

The attribute of `style=` allows us to do some inline css like `"display:none;"` which hides a html element its declared on.

I recommend checking out W3Schools for more on [html input tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Additionally you are trying to make the button into a link using the `<a>` tag, this is invalid, please take a look at this [Html forms and input page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) to see how to use the submit input type.

If you just want a link then I'd recommend looking at an [`<img>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for a button and an [`<a>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) around that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have comment privileges on this SE yet but I would say that IE is incapable if interpreting: `<input type="submit" a="" none;<="" display:="">`

When you open "input" you do not close it until after display. the addition of the "none;<" is probably interpreted as another attempt at a tag and breaking html. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but get rid of this:

```
none;<=""
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is a mess, but it actually works in IE8, so any problem you are seeing is caused by something outside the code you posted.

Browsers will ignore the crap inside the `input` tag and recognize it simply as `<input type="submit">`. Some browsers might conceivably choke on the “<” character there, but IE8 doesn’t.

The `a` element wrapper outside it has no effect as such.

Comment: i know, it's a mess. i solved it. i was an idiot for writing code like that